How to convert logstash to hex string after consuming binary data from kafka
My kafka value is byte array, is not text or json
How to convert logstash to hex string after consuming binary data from kafka
input config
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }

    tcp {
        port => 50000
    }
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "192.168.1.5:9092"
        group_id => "logstash"
        topics => ["xx","xxx"]
        decorate_events => true
        id => "log"
        codec => plain {
            charset => "BINARY"
            ecs_compatibility => "disabled"
        }
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        copy => { "[@metadata][kafka]" => "kafka" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
    }
}

But this will get a string of utf-8 encode.
I want to view the message as a hex string in kibana.
So what do I do now to achieve what I want.
